# How to efficiently determine the interval a given value is in?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following zone definitions for a value `x`:

- 'A' : x < 1
- 'B' :   1 <= x < 10
- 'C' :  10 <= x < 112
- 'D' : 112 <= x

I am looking for an efficient way to determine the zone for given values of `x`. I came up with:

```
borders = (1, 10, 112)

tst_values = (.2, 2, 22, 222)
for x in tst_values:
    z = next((i for b, i in zip(borders, 'ABC') if x < b), 'D')
    print(f" * Value {x:3g} is in zone '{z}'.")

# The output is:
# * Value 0.2 is in zone 'A'.
# * Value   2 is in zone 'B'.
# * Value  22 is in zone 'C'.
# * Value 222 is in zone 'D'.
```

What are the best practices for solving such a problem, especially if the number of zones, i.e., `len(borders)` is large. `borders` may contain an arbitrary list of (increasing) floats.

**Update** 
Rephrased question a little bit to address comments.

Comment: This is a simple logarithmic problem. Take the log of the number to get the digits..

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl There's no pattern to the zones - the borders may be an arbitrary list of increasing numbers. I updated the question, to make that clear.

Comment: "especially if the number borders is large" - Do you mean if you have many borders? Or do you mean the value of not so many borders is large?

Comment: @Dietrich are the test values always increasing in nature ?

Comment: @Leon The number of zones are large. The value of the zones can be represented by normal floats.

Comment: @AlbinPaul The test values may be sorted in any desired order beforehand.

Comment: @Dietrich did you check if the solutions work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To effectively find the range you are in a long list of sorted borders, I would suggest using a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Basically, you look in the middle of your array of borders, check if you are to big/small. Depending on that, you check the value at one/three quarters of the border-array's length. And so on.

This can easily be implemented using recursion by hand. Alternatively, you can use numpy's implementation [numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html), which YSelf pointed out. The latter will almost certainly be faster than the former.

When using `numpy.digitize`, your code would become:

```py
borders = (1, 10, 112)
values = (.2, 2, 22, 222)

for x in values:
    z = 'ABCD'[numpy.digitize(x, borders)]
    print(f" * Value {x:3g} is in zone '{z}'.")
```

Comment: [numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) implements this binary search.

Comment: Was not aware of `np.digitize()` -  that solves my problem nicely.

Answer (score 3):

An efficient way to do this would be to do a binary search through the borders. Python has a build in `bisect` library that will do this for you:

```
import bisect

borders = (1, 10, 112)
tst_values = (.2, 2, 22, 222)
    for x in tst_values:
    border_right = bisect.bisect_right(borders, x) # x < b
    # or
    border_left = bisect.bisect_left(borders, x)   # x > b
```

This will give you the index into borders that the value x falls into. You can then convert that index into a letter if you like.

Comment: Based on the usage of `<` and `<=` in OP's example, we wants `bisect_left`, or just `bisect`, which is an alias for `bisect_left`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want efficient way to solve this problem, use numpy vectorized operations using  [`np.greater_than`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.greater_equal.html#numpy.greater_equal) and [`np.less`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less_equal.html#numpy.less_equal) with [`outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html), then taking index values with [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)

```
a = np.greater_equal.outer(tst_values, [-np.inf, 1,10,112]) & \
    np.less.outer(tst_values, [1, 10,112, np.inf])

np.take(list('ABCD'), np.argmax(a, axis=1))
```

This works pretty efficiently. For 5 MM rows, it runs in less than a sec

```
%timeit (...)
922 ms ± 8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarks - it's the second choice after `np.digitize()` for me.